# Show event nearest to current day in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have a Wordpress collection of events to show which have a date field. I'm trying to display 2 out of x number of records in a small table on my homepage which will be the two nearest dates to today's (or tomorrow's, the next day, etc.) date. Currently I can only sort by the date with the largest value (i.e. July 10th 2014 is 'bigger' than 20th May).

Here's my code snippet:

```
$type = 'courses';

                       $args=array(
                      'post_type' => $type,
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
                      'order' => 'date_course',
                      'meta_key' => 'date_course', 'orderby' => 'date_timezone_get("Europe/Belfast")',
                      'posts_per_page' => 2

                    );
```

What should the appropriate value be for `orderby`?

**And the dates sample:**

Tuesday 10th June

Tuesday 3rd June

Wednesday 4th June

And currently the 10th and the 4th are displayed in the table and it should be the 3rd and 4th as they are nearer to today. Hope that is all clear!

Comment: Not a wordpress expert (far from it, I hate it), but the SQL would be something like: `SELECT *, ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), date_course)) as time_diff FROM courses ORDER BY time_diff ASC`

Comment: DanielD try to get and convert the result with mysql and simply view it in the array that would be much easier. Select CEIL(TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(now(), date_course ),'%H:%m:%s')/3600) AS hours from courses order by hours asc.

Comment: I don't have a MySQL implementation with my client's Wordpress. I'm looking for a way to do it as stated above.